# Spring Boot monitor JDBC Pool activities

Tags: java, spring-boot, jdbc

I'm facing with a frustrating problem with jdbc

`org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PoolExhaustedException: [...] Timeout: Pool empty. Unable to fetch a connection in 30 seconds, none available[size:4; busy:4; idle:0; lastwait:30000]`

I found several solutions here about how to fix it but this is not the point.

I'd like to see from the logs WHO is creating these connections and not releasing.

Do you know some spring boot configuration or logback setup to show the event where a jdbc connection is taken from or returned to the pool?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried to enable DEBUG log level? If no, try to enable, it might get you some insight of what is going on.

Comment: The WHO is always going to be the same if your pool is setup with one set of credentials.

Comment: Profiling! Java Mission Control (on not-production environment)

Comment: @DaShaun the "_who_" could also be a thread name which you can then match with a thread dump – I don't know if that would be possible though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If following Paul's recommendation doesn't help, my next step would be to add:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Then use the /trace and /metrics endpoints to figure out whats happening.